# Choosing what tab a user is on, accross multiple pages

Tags: php, menu, tabs, modx

I am currently creating a website with tabs.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/chosentab.png/ (It wont let me embed the image)

As you can see, there is a tab, called classPvP that is selected, and it is done so by adding a "**selected**" in the tag's class.
However, this website is going to be like a wiki, and as such have many different pages, and I don't want to have to create a seperate 'template' (if you will) for every page with a different selected tab, because then updating or changing something across all those templates would be very difficult.

I am trying to use this code to add in the desired class when you have chosen a tab:

```
<?php
//Defining the variables
$a="[[*menutitle]]";
if ($a=="classpvp"){
echo "selected";
} else {
echo $a;
} ?>
```

With the CMS (MODx) I'm using, **[[*menutitle]]** is replaced by whatever tab I want to have'selected'. However, for some reason, the if statement is not being run, but the echo is outputting that the value of $a is **classpvp** .

This is seriously confusing me, as to why the if statement isn't being run, yet the value is correct - Am I storing something poorly?
(Sorry, I'm very new to PHP)

(Keeping in mind that **[[TabSelectClassPvP]]** is replaced with the php code)
When used var_dump($a) (as suggested), the class turns from :

```
<li class="navTab [[TabSelectClassPvP]]">
ClassPvP
</li>
```

to:

```
<li class="navTab string(14) " classpvp"="">
ClassPvP
</li>
```

The exact php code being run is:

```
<?php
//Defining the variables
$a="[[*menutitle]]";
var_dump($a);
if ($a=="classpvp"){
echo "selected";
} else {
echo $a;
}
```

Thanks,
Muffinjello

P.S. -
I'm open to new ways of doing this, maybe something that retrieves information from an HTML ID?

Comment: can you post output of var_dump($a); before the if statement

Comment: Done! Added it to the question, @AydinHassan , thanks!

Comment: Note the space at the beginning of the string :)

Comment: @AydinHassan Nope, that isn't it :(

Comment: @Crisp, how do I make it become a useable string?

Comment: So `if(trim($a) == "classpvp") {` still doesn't work as you want?

Comment: Nope :( Sadly it doesn't.

Comment: last one: if(strpos($a,"classpvp") !== false) {

Comment: Nope T_T might it have anything to do with the vardump being string(14) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the WAyFinder package for your menus, it will automatically place the 'active' rule in your class attribute. http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Wayfinder if you want to use something different the &hereClass  is the c=value you want to specify in your WayFinder call.

**UPDATE**

if you want to use the menutitle of the current resource in your snippet there are 2 ways to do it, pass it in from the snippet call:

```
<li class="navTab [[!TabSelectClassPvP? &a='[[*menutitle]]']]">
```

And your snippet looks like:

```
<?php
// Defining the variables
// $a="[[*menutitle]]";
// var_dump($a);

if ($a=="classpvp"){
echo "selected";
} else {
echo $a;
}
```

[you probably should check to see if $a has been passed]

or you can query the current page directly in your snippet:

```
<?php
// Defining the variables
// $a="[[*menutitle]]";
// var_dump($a);

$a = $modx->resource->get('menutitle');

if ($a=="classpvp"){
echo "selected";
} else {
echo $a;
}
```

As the modx object always assumes 'the current resource' you can grab any of the resource fields o TVs in your snippets like that.

Comment: Erm, I don't really understand how to use WayFinder, mind giving me an example of the snippet, in this case? :) Thanks!

I'll be sure to vote you up

Comment: Your minimum wayfinder call is [[Wayfinder? &startId='0']] if you just stick that in your template it should output a [barely] formatted navigation menu for your site. ~ if you are going to be using modx you will need to read and understand the wayfinder docs as it is about the only way to automatically build a navigation bar/menu. Fortunately wayfinder is also one of the best documented extras.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for letting me know. I will definitely do a lot of research into it to see if I can get it working, if push comes to shove. For now I'll see if I can get my static menu to work well, since I don't really have enough time to learn wayfinder :/ At any rate, time to approve your answer ! :)

Comment: just taking a quick look, your snippet, $a="[[*menutitle]]"; will never get a value passed for $a ~ you have to pass that value into the snippet from your call. <li class="navTab [[!TabSelectClassPvP? &a='[[*menutitle]]']]">

Comment: o.o Mind expanding, a bit more? So I would just have the php current script, but not define the value for &a (in the actual call itself), and when I put it like that, it would properly assign the value and run the 'if' statement?

Comment: I know this might not be appropriate, but.... Have I told you I love you? But, I'm cheating on you with your answer. - Thanks a lot for the help! You've just saved me a lot of frustration! :) Maybe take a look at my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027803/modx-resource-alias-breaking-plugin-using-pages-with-in-the-url-reso)?