# MODx - Resource Alias breaking plugin - Using pages with "/" in the URL? ( /resources/page.html )

Tags: php, plugins, modx, breadcrumbs

I currenlty have a MODx website setup, and I am wondering if it's proper to have my links look like this (And by that I mean my resource alias):

> myurl.com/help/configuration/basics.html

Putting the slash in the URL like that... is it a bad practice? My main problem is that this [breadcrumb](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Breadcrumbs) plugin seems to no longer work... :(
I want to have this breadcrumb plugin operational again, if someone would mind helping me.

The Error:

When say using the breadcrumb to link to a page that's *myurl.com/code/landing.html* and the current page is **myurl.com/help/configuration/basics.html**, it will then redirect you to a link that doesnt exist, that looks like this:

**myurl.com/help/configuration/***code/landing.html*

As you can see, it is appending the latter portion of the new page's url, but it is not properly removing the URL of the current page, as it only removes the current URL up to the '/' slash....

Does anyone know how to fix this? Possibly a way to make it so that instead of doing it's current "remove" and "append" thing, I can change **breadcrumbs.class.php** to take the value of the links as if I had clicked the link with the "view" button on the MODx manager? I'm not an expert at php, and it is a must for this to work.
Or are there other alternatives to creating the " / " effect in my links, rather than just putting it in the resource alias? (As I want the site to follow a logical, readable, order)

Answer (score 1):

With all things modx, clear the cache, even if you don't think it could be the issue ~ modx is very aggressive about caching stuff.

Though this kinda sounds like maybe your base href tag may be set to `<base href="" />`, possibly in your templates it may look like:

```
<base href="[[++site_url]]"></base>
```

where site_url is set dynamically [it's not a system setting so don't look for it] in your /core/config/config.inc.php as $modx_base_url ... if that value is blank that could be causing the issue.

Also check your rewrite rules in your .htaccess to see what the rewrite base is. [it should be / ]

then refresh your cache... ;)

Comment: So... What should I set the $modx_base_url to? "resources.myurl.com/" from "/" ???

Comment: "/" is correct. What value does your base href have? also did you modify any of the breadcrumb chunks? a look at them would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I did modify them a bit-- Here is the code on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RynDsYPN)

Comment: you modified the breadcrumb class, not the chunk? probably not a good idea, any update will wipe your changes. and what and why did you change the class?

Comment: Yeah, the original chunk was commented telling me where to edit the file, with all the settings - the original class file that I sent is also commented for editting, so that's what I did.. though I didn't change anything to do with links....